# After changing the angularjs in my application I am getting error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-resource

I developed an application which uses 1.0.1 version : https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js

Now I need to use latest version as to use new functionality so I tried replacing with 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js

and I am getting error. [image]

error :

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11/$injector/modulerr?p0=audiapp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.11%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%0At%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.11%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%0AYb%2Fl.%24injector%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.11%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%0Ac%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.11%2Fangular.min.js%3A30%0Ad%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.11%2Fangular.min.js%3A30%0AYb%2Fe%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.11%2Fangular.min.js%3A29%0Aq%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.11%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%0Ae%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.11%2Fangular.min.js%3A29%0AYb%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.11%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%0AXb%2Fc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.11%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%0AXb%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.11%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%0ASc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.11%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%0A%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.11%2Fangular.min.js%3A201%0Ax.Callbacks%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55165%2FScripts%2Fjquery-1.10.2.min.js%3Fv%3D1.0%3A4%0Ax.Callbacks%2Fp.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55165%2FScripts%2Fjquery-1.10.2.min.js%3Fv%3D1.0%3A4%0A.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55165%2FScripts%2Fjquery-1.10.2.min.js%3Fv%3D1.0%3A4%0Aq%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A55165%2FScripts%2Fjquery-1.10.2.min.js%3Fv%3D1.0%3A4%0A
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js
>   Line 6

Apart from this I am also using angular-resource.js version v1.0.2 and http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular-route.min.js.

Can any one please suggest what is wrong here?

All the references : 
      [image]

Comment: can you post error text also?

Comment: are you using routes? did you include this resource js file?

Comment: @Nikhil : Error added.

Comment: @Dalorzo : Yes I am using routes and i have added js for that.

Comment: @SamirShah it seems you haven't installed ngRoute. Have you installed it?

Comment: @Nikhil : to install means to have a reference in the project right? I am sorry i am very new to Angular JS.

Comment: @SamirShah ya you are right. Is it possible to place some code in jsfiddle? want to see how are you including all the required js file?

Comment: @Nikhil : Image added with all the references in project

Comment: Have you load the ngRoute module in your application by adding it as a dependent module: e.g. `angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);` ?

Comment: No I haven't added i have just added angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])

Comment: add ngRoute also and see if it resolves the issue..

Comment: @Nikhil Hi Nikhil I got stuck at some other problem of AngularJs can you please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718083/excel-file-not-getting-after-returning-from-angularjs-service